# javascript_include_tag inconsistent behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sprockets

Working with Ruby 2.0 and Rails 4.0, I'm seeing a different behavior on my asset pipeline and I'm not sure why.  Here's the gist of it...

I have in my ./app/assets/javascripts folder an application.js.coffee and google_analytics.js.coffee file.

In my app/views/layouts/application.html.haml, I have the following two lines:

```
= javascript_include_tag "application"
= javascript_include_tag "google_analytics"
```

This produces the following in the rendered page once deployed to production:

```
<script src="/assets/application-f15feb4200e0d1db4963a00b28fbe9ca.js"></script>
<script src="/javascripts/google_analytics.js"></script>
```

Note that the `application` include is compiled into the assets pipeline as expected, while the `google_analytics` script is not.

In development mode, everything's served from the assets pipe without the fingerprints as expected:

```
<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1"></script>
<!-- several other includes suppressed for brevity here -->
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1"></script>
<script src="/assets/google_analytics.js?body=1"></script>
```

I also checked the production deployment and noted that `google_analytics` doesn't get pre-compiled and fingerprinted.

EDIT:  After getting the comments and answers below, added the following to config/environments/production.rb and attempted another deploy:

```
ComingSoon::Application.configure do
  config.serve_static_assets = false
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.assets.version = '1.0'

  config.assets.precompile += ['google_analytics.js.coffee']
end
```

Why is the sprockets assets pipeline not pre-compiling the `google_analytics` script and serving it up like it does the `application script`? how do I fix this?

Comment: How did you check that the google script isn't being precompiled? If its in your assets folder and you have //= require_tree . in your application.js then it defintely should be getting compiled.

Comment: its not a require in the application.js.coffee and, as a general rule, I don't do "require_tree" -- Its separate because I want to include it only on production with a conditional include.  that is "= javascript_include('google_analytics") if Rails.env == 'production'"  To check that it wasn't precompiled, I noted that it did not emit a message for this file during cap production deploy but other assets did and I also logged into production to check the public/assets folder and it is missing there as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the google script to the precompile list in your config/environments/production.rb file on the config.assets.precompile setting. More here: [What is the purpose of config.assets.precompile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012434/what-is-the-purpose-of-config-assets-precompile)

Comment: According to documentation from that SO answer..."The default matcher for compiling files includes application.js, application.css and all files that do not end in js or css: [ /\w+\.(?!js|css).+/, /application.(css|js)$/ ]" which should mean "google_analytics.js.coffee" should get picked up automatically.

Comment: Not if its not in your application.js manifest. When it's not you need to add it to the precompile list.

Comment: Followed instructions to add google_analytics.js.coffee to the list of assets to precompile, but behavior is unchanged.

Comment: capistrano's precompiling assets... executing "cd -- /home/deploy/sites/coming_soon/production/app/releases/20140130174823 && RAILS_ENV=production RAILS_GROUPS=assets bundle exec rake assets:precompile"  -- is this not sufficient?

Comment: Solved!  Do not include the "coffee" extension on the file name.  The setting should be: "config.assets.precompile += ['google_analytics.js']"

Answer (score 1):

The google_analytics file needs to be added to the precompile list:

```
config.assets.precompile += ['google_analytics.js.coffee', ..]
```

Add above to your `application.rb` or `production.rb` as desired.

Note: Unless you have required the file in the application.js manifest file, through a direct `require` or through a `require_tree`, the js doesn't get compiled.

Comment: Followed instructions to add google_analytics.js.coffee to the list of assets to precompile, but behavior is unchanged.  Updated question to show my changes.